# Vaadin: How To programmatically perform a KeyPressEvent on TAB-Button?

Tags: java, button, vaadin, shortcut

is there a way to programmatically perform a Button Press Event i.e for the `TAB`-Button in Vaadin? I have to write a test for a ShortCutListener, which listens to  ShortCut `ShortCutAction.KeyEvent.TAB`.

I have tried something like that:

```
Button button = new Button();

        button.addShortcutListener(new ShortcutListener("ShortCut", ShortcutAction.KeyCode.TAB, null) {

            private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

            @Override
            public void handleAction(Object sender, Object target) {
                System.out.println("Click!");

            }
        });

        button.setClickShortcut(ShortcutAction.KeyCode.TAB, null);

        button.click();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is triggering the click event when pressing the tab key, you could do the following:

```
Button button = new Button();

button.addClickListener(new Button.ClickListener() {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    public void buttonClick(final ClickEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Click!");
    }
});

button.setClickShortcut(ShortcutAction.KeyCode.TAB);

button.click();
```

Using a Vaadin `Button` to do something useful on a key press is probably not a good idea, except if the keypress is a shortcut to clicking on the button (which the `setClickShortcut` method lets you define).

---

If you want to do something specific on a keypress, something that is different from what your buttons do, you should define an action handler on your `Window` or `Panel`, as [Vaadin recommends](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-shortcuts.html#advanced.shortcuts.actions).

Comment: thats hat I want with the only difference that the tab-key is pressed programmatically....how i do that?

Comment: Set a flag or add some meta information to your prog TAG press/click

Comment: @HakanKiyar Can you please explain the rationale behind wanting to simulate a tab keypress? Button probably isn't the right control to react to keypresses, they are focused on reacting to click events but they enable to activate the click event with a key shortcut.

Comment: I have implemented a ShortcutListener for doing some logic when pressing the TAB-Button - now I want to write a Junit-Test for that logic for that I should be able to trigger a TAB-Keypress-Event programmtically

Comment: If AbstractClientConnector.fireEvent(EventObject) was visible, it would probably be the way to go but it's not. Does your button do anything different when you press the tab key than when you click on it?

Comment: No the shortcutlistener does not react to `button.click()` - or what do you mean?

Comment: @HakanKiyar I'm wondering if your button does something when you click it and if it does, does it do something different than when you press the tab key and your button picks it up and reacts to it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106917/discussion-between-hakan-kiyar-and-valentin).