# Vaadin Accordion with a Button in the tab

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin8

Vaadin [`Accordion`](https://vaadin.com/docs/v8/framework/layout/layout-accordion.html) allows an icon on its tab. It can be done by its method

> Tab addTab(Component c, String caption, Resource icon)

My question is - can that `Resource icon` be made an image button? So that there'll be a `Button` that can be clicked in the accordion tab. I know that an image can be turned into and used as a `Button`.

I saw some of the relevant other articles including [Vaadin 7 add buttons into Accordion com.vaadin.ui.TabSheet.Tab caption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38550981/vaadin-7-add-buttons-into-accordion-com-vaadin-ui-tabsheet-tab-caption) and [Vaadin: How To programmatically perform a KeyPressEvent on TAB-Button?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36131959/vaadin-how-to-programmatically-perform-a-keypressevent-on-tab-button).

TIA.

Comment: Can you give more detail on what you try to achieve? Why would you want a clickable button in the accordion tab? The tab in itself is clickable and will show the associated content. What would the purpose of the button be?